# AVPlayer video not recognize and did not play the video

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

i have a video in the s3 Bucket that contains videos like 1.mp4,2.mp4 and so on. Now there is a server that request the video to s3 bucket as we hit the server and i get the link as.And in my app i get the link as **"https://.....playerClass=HD&playerCode=HD1&fileName=1.mp4"**. I tried to play this link through my AVPlayer swift but ended with dark screen. i have looked almost all the methods found in SO. I don't know what actually is the problem.If i run that link the video will be downloaded in web but app does not show anything. in that case how can i play that video in AVPlayer.

These videos can be played: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4". But the link i generate cannot be played.
Here is my code:

```
  @IBAction func btnplayClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
let url = ModuleServices.getFullRequestUrlForStream(playerClass, playerCode: sessionInfo!.code, fileName: "\(currentIndex).mp4")
     let path = url
    let url = NSURL(string: path)
    // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true)
    {
        player.play()
    }
   }
```

Comment: facing same issue.Any help, did you resolve this problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue. any solution?